# Codeigniter error Undefined property: Events::$session after laod to server

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

After uploading codeigniter application to internet i got erorr:

> *"Message: Undefined property: Events::$session Filename: libraries/Ion_auth.php Line Number: 125"*

This problem comes from Session library. This library is loaded corectly and worked in my computer. I tried to create new empty application in same server and test:

> $this->load->library('Session');
>      echo $this->session_id();

and i got the same problem. Server is using PHP 5.3 i was using PHP 5.5.12. I changed first letter to uppercase, i did not help. Everything works fine in my computer.

My controllers beggining:

> defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
>         require_once SYSDIR . '/libraries/Driver.php';
>         require_once SYSDIR . '/libraries/Session/Session.php';

```
class Events extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('Javascript');
        $this->load->library('Form_validation');
        $this->load->library('Email');
        $this->load->library('Session');
        $this->load->library('Ion_auth');
    }
```

All in all it looks like session is not loaded.